# How to Sort Nested Object By Property With Same String, Move Values in Ascending Order & Create Id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I currently have an object with nested object arrays that looks like this:

```
const gyms: any = {
  gymOne: [
    { class: "yoga", name: "spin class 0" },
    { class: "spin", name: "spin class 1" },
  ],
  gymTwo: [
    { class: "spin", name: "a spin class 3" },
    { class: "weightlifting", name: "weightlifting class 1" },
  ],
};

for (let key in gyms) {
        if (typeof gyms[key] === "object") {
            console.log(gyms[key]);   
        } else {
            console.log("");    
        }
}
```

My goal is to create a new result object that disregards the keys (gymOne, gymTwo), lists all of the classes based on same class name (i.e. all spin classes should be together), and reorder it so that the names are alphabetical in ascending order.

I'm rusty with JavaScript, however this is how I started out to get the classes and names

```
for (let key in gyms) {
        if (typeof gyms[key] === "object") {
            console.log(gyms[key]);   
        } else {
            console.log("");    
        }
}
```

I'll likely need to create a new object like `let resultObj = []` to hold the new sorted order.

I'm grateful for any advice. Thank you.

Edit: This is the current console output.

```
[LOG]: [{
  "class": "yoga",
  "name": "spin class 0"
}, {
  "class": "spin",
  "name": "spin class 1"
}] 
[LOG]: [{
  "class": "spin",
  "name": "a spin class 3"
}, {
  "class": "weightlifting",
  "name": "weightlifting class 1"
}]
```

Desired sample output example:

```
const resultObj = [
    { class: "spin", name: "a spin class 3" },
    { class: "spin", name: "spin class 1" },
    { class: "weightlifting", name: "weightlifting class 1" },
    { class: "yoga", name: "spin class 0" },  
]
```

Comment: Good catch, I went ahead and edited.

Comment: do you have a result of the above?

Comment: I updated the post with the current console output for reference.

Comment: How about `Object.values(gyms).flatMap(e => e.filter(e => e.class === "spin"))`? I'm not sure what your expected output is.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: when you say: "and reorder it so that the names are alphabetical in ascending order", do you want to order by `class` or by `name`?

Comment: I'm looking to organize by same class property (i.e. all 'yoga' are output, then all spin). The class will be the key in the object. The value will be the name. Once they're all sorted by class, I'll then alphabetize the name so that they're in order based on letter of name. Going to create a sample output to share.

Comment: I updated the post with the desired sample output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a flat array of all values from the object and sort by `class` and `name`.

```js
const
    gyms = { gymOne: [{ class: "yoga", name: "spin class 0" }, { class: "spin", name: "spin class 1" }], gymTwo: [{ class: "spin", name: "a spin class 3" }, { class: "weightlifting", name: "weightlifting class 1" }] },
    items = Object.values(gyms).flat();
    
items.sort((a, b) => 
    a.class.localeCompare(b.class) ||
    a.name.localeCompare(b.name) 
);

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For a more dynamic approach, you could use an array of keys for sorting.

```js
const
    gyms = { gymOne: [{ class: "yoga", name: "spin class 0" }, { class: "spin", name: "spin class 1" }], gymTwo: [{ class: "spin", name: "a spin class 3" }, { class: "weightlifting", name: "weightlifting class 1" }] },
    items = Object.values(gyms).flat(),
    keys = ['class', 'name'];
    
items.sort((a, b) => {
    let r;
    keys.some(k => r = a[k].localeCompare(b[k]));
    return r;
});

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this could be to:

1. Combine all the items in a single array
2. Sort the array

Alternatively you could do both steps at once, but seems like you are still getting comfortable with JS, so I wouldn't worry about optimizing too much now.

```js
// first, get an array containing all the object values, this will be an array of arrays
Object.values(gyms)
  // flat returns a new array with the sub-array elements concatenated into it
  .flat()
  // sort the keys, first by `class` and then by `name`
  .sort((a, b) => {
    return a.class.localeCompare(b.class) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name) 
  })
```